# What is the right way to qualify a noun with a measurment descriptor?

Tags: technical, modifiers, quantifiers

Suppose I have, in an experiment, *a metallic film that has a thickness of 10 nanometers.*

What is the right short, perhaps technical, way to qualify this film with a modifier that describes this characteristic?

(Suppose that nanometer is necessarily abbreviated as "nm").

- We used a 10 nm film.
- We used a 10-nm film.
- We used a 10 nm-film.

I have seen all the options in one place or another.

What if I want to be more specific at the price of more verbosity?

- We used a 10 nm thick film.
- We used a 10-nm thick film.
- We used a 10 nm-thick film.
- We used a 10-nm-thick film.
- We used a 10-nm thick-film.
- ... other?

**What do you think is the best option for each group?**

Comment: Do the following answer your question?

[1](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/124931/do-i-need-a-hyphen-in-1000-l-bioreactor-hyphens-with-abbreviated-units-of-mea)

[2](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/89931/usage-of-hyphens-with-numeric-measurements)

[3](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/112297/hyphen-in-physical-quantities-before-nouns)

Comment: @dubious, yes, it answers me that there is no consensus. Nobody seems to recommend the hyphen before the noun.

Comment: Or this one? https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/105553/should-thin-spaces-be-used-between-numerals-and-units. I find thin spaces in front of units are handy in compound structures like these. Latex does this, but alas, we can't use it here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [13 Month Old or 13-Month-Old?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/302713/13-month-old-or-13-month-old) coupled with [5-min-video vs 5 min video vs 5min video](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/209042/5-min-video-vs-5-min-video-vs-5min-video) 'Hyphens should only be used if the symbol for the unit is not used.' So << We used a 10 nm thick film. >>

Comment: See pages 6-8 in the siunitx package for Latex. https://texdoc.org/serve/siunitx/0